# How to filter based on multiple conditions in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
    count       DATE           state    District     Gender     
0   1604.0      2020-03-11      AN      Nicobar      None   
1   13.0        2020-03-11      UP      Noida        Male   
2   4.0         2020-03-11      KA      Banglore     Female 
3   6.0         2020-03-11      PB      Chandigarh   None   
4   20.0        2020-03-11      MP      Indore       Female
```

I have to apply different filters based on DATE,state,District and Gender simultaneously.

1. Date will be filter out based on start and end date criteria.
2. By default all 'state' are displaying if any particular 'state' is selected then state filter will be combined with date filter.
3. By default all 'District' are displaying if any particular 'District' is selected then District filter will be combined with above filters.
4. By default all 'Gender' are displaying if any particular 'Gender' is selected then Gender filter will be combined with above filters.

How to apply the above filters combined in pandas dataframe  (combined query in one step and working simultaneously)? I currently use if-else clauses. Could any one suggest me better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select certain rows in a DataFrame based on their column values, you can make boolean masks. For example:

```
mask = (df.A == 1) & (df.B > 3)
df[mask]
```

This would only select the rows in your DataFrame where A == 1 and B > 3.